# Existe alguma diferença entre essas duas maneiras de Bubble Sort°

Tags: c, bubblesort

Existe alguma diferença entre esses códigos?

esse:

```
    void bubble_sort(int array[], int n) 
    {
    int count = -1;
    while (count != 0)
    {
        count = 0;
        int aux;
        for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] > array[i + 1])
            {
                aux = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = aux;
                count++;
            }
        }
        n--;
    }
    }
```

e esse:

```
     void bubbleSort(int array[], int n) 
       { 
       int i, j, aux; 
       for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
       { 
           for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
           { 
               if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
               {
                 aux = array[i];
                 array[i] = array[i + 1];
                 array[i + 1] = aux;
               } 
           }
       }
```

*principalmente em questão de tempo

Comment: A complexidade de melhor caso no primeiro código é O(n), enquanto no segundo código é O(n^2). Isso quer dizer que, em um vetor já ordenado, o primeiro programa percorrerá apenas uma vez a lista, enquanto o segundo percorrerá n vezes as sublistas de tamanho de 1 a n.

Comment: Grato, retirou as minhas dúvidas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem autores que chamam a primeira versão de "otimizada".
Mas se pode chamar a segunda de "burra" ou ao menos de "ingênua" --- para ser politicamente correto.

Se você vai ficar classificando lá o vetor gigante durante horas e chega uma hora que durante um loop todinho você não troca ninguém de lugar quer dizer que o vetor já está em ordem e você nunca mais vai trocar ninguém de lugar. E assim você continuar no loop descendo e comparando e
comparando não vai mais mudar nada: só está perdendo tempo até chegar ao fim, sem mais bolhas --- *bubbles*

Como essas implementações comuns de BubbleSort() usam os índices a partir do início e a memória tem endereços crescentes então esse devia ser o AnchorSort já que os elementos afundam como uma âncora ao invés de subir como em geral as bolhas fazem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Em alguns casos a primeira versão, com while, pode terminar com menos iterações que a segunda.

A segunda versão está com alguns erros, como usar o `i` ao invés do `j` ao fazer a troca de posições no array.

Comment: Grato pela resposta, farei as devidas correções.

Comment: Mas fica a dúvida.... nesse caso é preferível a primeira? Por terminar com menos iterações

Comment: Sim. O algoritmo é o mesmo. Apenas é meio besta ficar iterando de novo e de novo sem ver se já está ordenado. Imagine uma amostra com meio milhão de itens,e por acaso quase todos em ordem... E inverter o sentido dos loops seria mais de acordo, começando de baixo e subindo como as bolhas em geral fazem